# A necessary and sufficient condition of Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $l\geqq 2$ be natural number.
And let $f$ be a Lebesgue-measurable function and suppose $f$ is non negative.

Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} l^n \cdot m(A_n)$ converges where $m$ is Lebesgue measure and $A_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R^n} \ | \ l^n \leqq f(x)<l^{n+1} \}.$

I'm not sure my proof is correct.

**My proof**

First, suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} l^n \cdot m(A_n)$ converges.

Let $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n.$

Note that $\displaystyle\int_{\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n} f(x) dx=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{A_n} f(x) dx$ since  $A_j\cap A_k=\emptyset$ for $j\neq k$ and $A^c=\emptyset$ since $A=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^n} \ | \ f(x)\geqq 0\}.$

Then,
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int |f(x)| dx&=\displaystyle\int f(x) dx\\
&=\int_{A} f(x) dx +\int_{A^c} f(x) dx\\
&=\int_{\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n} f(x) dx +\int_{\emptyset} f(x) dx\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{A_n} f(x) dx +0\\
&<\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{A_n} l^{n+1} dx \\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  l^{n+1} \cdot m(A_n) \\
&=l \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  l^{n} \cdot m(A_n) \\
&<\infty.
\end{align}
Thus $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  l^{n} \cdot m(A_n)
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  l^{n} \displaystyle\int_{A_n} dx \\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  \displaystyle\int_{A_n} l^{n} dx \\
&\leqq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  \displaystyle\int_{A_n} f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int_{\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n} f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int_{A} f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int_{A} f(x) dx +\displaystyle\int_{\emptyset} f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int_{A} f(x) dx +\displaystyle\int_{A^c} f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int f(x) dx \\
&=\displaystyle\int |f(x)| dx \\
&<\infty.
\end{align}

Is this proof correct?

Comment: This looks good! Nice job setting $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter way, same basic idea:
Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} l^n \cdot 1_{A_n}(x)$ (the $1_{A_n}$ is the indicator function of $A_n$).
Then $0 \le g(x) \le f(x) \le l \cdot g(x)$.

If $\int|f|< \infty$ then $\int|g|< \infty $ and similarly the other way around.